# Wordpress Avada: Css doesnt work on Mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, responsive

i wrote a css-code to modify the text. I filled the code in the "custom css".
It works perfectly in desktop but not in mobile.

Heres my code:

```
.test 1
    {
       background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #eff1ff 10%, #000 100%);
       -webkit-background-clip: text;
       -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        font-family: "SF Pro Display","SF Pro Icons","Helvetica Neue","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;
    }
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you used the inspect facility in  your browser dev tools to see what is setting the styling when the device is narrower? There may be some media queries overwriting your settings.

Answer (score -1):

/* add your custom CSS in media query for mobile screen size */

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.test 1
    {
       background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #eff1ff 10%, #000 100%) !important;
       -webkit-background-clip: text;
       -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        font-family: "SF Pro Display","SF Pro Icons","Helvetica Neue","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;
    }
}
```